# TCP/IP monitor missing from Eclipse ADT (Android Development Tools)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to do a good bit of work with HTTP and TCP requests for an Android App. However when I go to Window->Preferences->Run/Debug there is no TCP/IP monitor setting visible and if I go to Window->Show View->Other there is no TCP/IP monitor to be found.

So why is this tool missing from my Eclipse ADT? Is there a way of installing it?

Comment: There are many free-standing networking monitor tools available. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is one that is popular.

Comment: Wireshard doesn't work with localhost.

Comment: You can also try fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP/IP monitor is included in Eclipse Web Tools, they are bundled in the Eclipse EE edition, but can be downloaded separately here:  http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/

Comment: What am I supposed to download though? The WebTools downloads page has loads of options - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.4.1/R-3.4.1-20120917174803/

Comment: Your two clicks away.  At the bottom of that page is section called Traditional Zip Files.  Under that there are there choices.  Most people want the first one (wtp4x).  The second one includes all of the source code.  They say they prefer people use the repo's, but I'm old school

Answer (score 0):

The TCP/IP Monitor is an Eclipse plug-in: it isn't necessarily installed by default.

It's part of "WTP" (Web Tools Platform):

- http://www.javablog.fr/eclipse-tcpip-monitor-view.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

Comment: So what jar am I supposed to download? That tutorial doesn't tell me I actually need to download?